# Get base64 version of password

Tags: bash, shell, base64, echo

I have this command:

```
echo -n "cdt_main!@#$" | base64
```

that fails with:

```
bash: !@#$": event not found
```

lulz b/c of the special characters. 
So my best guess is that this is correct:

```
echo -n "cdt_main\!\@#\$" | base64
```

at least this is b/c there is no error now. Unfortunately I cannot test the base64 version password until I know that it's right - I have only one chance to get it right o/w something will blow up. **Does that look right to you?**

Using the decoding trick, I have:

```
echo -n "cdt_main\!\@#\$" | base64 | base64 --decode
```

which yields:

```
cdt_main\!\@#$
```

given that output, not sure if this is working as planned, *because slashes are in there*.

Comment: `echo -n "cdt_main\!\@#\$" | base64 | base64 -d` and check.

Comment: @tkausl good ideer, thanks let me try it

Comment: on a mac `base64 -d` is not a valid option, hmmm let me look up

Comment: `base64 --decode` works, but it returns a string with slashes and I don't think that's gonna work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that bash's history expansion is turned on.  Unless you history expansion is something that you actively want and use, the solution is to turn it off.

Observe that this fails with `event not found`:

```
$ echo -n "cdt_main!@#$" | base64
bash: !@#: event not found
```

But, this succeeds:

```
$ set +H
$ echo -n "cdt_main!@#$" | base64
Y2R0X21haW4hQCMk
```

`set +H` turns off history expansion.

#### Alternative: use single quotes

For strings inside double quotes, the shell will perform a wide variety of expansions.  To prevent that, put strings instead in single quotes.

For example, the following succeeds even with history expansion turned on:

```
$ set -H
$ echo -n 'cdt_main!@#$' | base64
Y2R0X21haW4hQCMk
```

#### Portable approach

The `-n` option to `echo` is not supported by all shells.  For a more portable solution, one should, as [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) suggests, use `printf`:

```
printf "%s" 'cdt_main!@#$' | base64
```

Comment: Nice thanks, that LGTM, so I guess I am safe because I don't have to escape any other char, but if I did I might have more problems

Comment: I am guessing that the completely generic bash solution would to turn off all interpreted characters that are declared in "strings" - is there a bash flag for that? that is the generic solution for all people w my problem, I believe.

Comment: It is not that bad: Just put the string in single quotes.  In that way, the _only_ problematic character is a single quote.

Comment: Thanks that would be a good to add as a second part to your answer, thx

Comment: @AlexanderMills OK.  Single-quotes added to the answer.

Comment: Another possible problem is that some implementations of `echo` (in some modes) will print "-n "  as part of the output string (and then go ahead and append the linefeed that it was supposed to suppress). I'd use `printf "%s" 'cdt_main!@#$'` instead of `echo`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Very true.  Thanks.  Answer updated with a `printf` (POSIX) solution.

Comment: What does the -n option do as in echo -n?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Normally, `echo` appends a newline character to anything it prints.  `-n` tells it not to.

Answer (score 1):

@John1024 is right, but an even more generic solution is to use:

```
echo -n 'cdt_main!@#$' | base64
```

single quotes `'` means the characters in the string aren't interpreted by bash, very nice.