# Bash scripting: Encoding string to base64 into a variable

Tags: bash, base64, command-substitution

I have a `username` and `password` variables. I want to encode them to base64 with the format of `username:password`.

```
#!/bin/bash
username=username
password=password

echo Encoding username/password...
echo $username:$password | base64
```

That works, but I'm not sure how to put the output in a variable instead of writing it to the console.

On a side note, why is the output different than a website like https://www.base64encode.org/?

Comment: How this question is even a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308934/get-base64-version-of-password is beyond me. I mean, this one asks specifically about assigning the output to a variable, whilst the other is merely trying to understand why the command isn't working. Not only that, but its existing answers don't show how to register the output into a variable either. They're two different questions.

Answer (score 8):

Using `$( ... )`, store the result in a variable.
And use `-n` to not include LF.

```
var=$(echo -n $username:$password | base64)
```

Comment: Avoid `echo -n` which is not standard. Prefer `printf instead`:
`var=$(printf '%s:%s' "$username" "$password" | base64)`